Solving Sequence Using Riemann Sum
I am currently in my second calculus course and my professor asked me to evaluate the limit of a sequence.
$$ b_k = \frac{1}{9k+1} + \frac{1}{9k+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{20k} $$
We did a similar problem in class where we did it with the sequence  $ a_n=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$ and we used a Riemann sum to evaluate this sequence and it gave an answer of ln(2). How would I approach this problem with the same technique of using a Riemann sum and then turning it into an easy integral to solve. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

You know the limit of $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$. What about the limit of $\frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{3n}$? The limit of $\frac{1}{9n+1} + \frac{1}{9n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{10n}$? The limit of $\frac{1}{19n+1} + \frac{1}{19n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{20n}$?

Study the expression ${1\over k}(kb_k)$
